# Spring Boot 3 with RESTDOCS

Tags: spring-boot, spring-restdocs

I was using spring-restdocs with SB2.7.9

Now we migrated to SB3.0.6. I am using gradle plugin (kotlin DSL) `id("org.asciidoctor.jvm.convert") version "3.3.2"`

Libraries are versions:

`spring-restdocs-asciidoctor-3.0.0.jar`

`spring-restdocs-core-3.0.0.jar`

`spring-restdocs-mockmvc-3.0.0.jar`

I have my custom template under `<project_path>/src/test/resources/org/springframework/restdocs/templates/request-parameters.snippet`

During execution of gradle task `asciidoctor` i am getting `WARNING: rest/my_complex_adoc_file.adoc: line 9: Snippet request-parameters not found at <project_path>/build/generated-snippets/zip-cities-find/request-parameters.adoc for operation zip-cities-find` (and yes, they are not really there)

And in `<project_path>/documentation/rest/my_complex_adoc_file.adoc` i have it like

```
operation::zip-cities-find[snippets='http-request,request-parameters,http-response,response-fields,links']
```

Gradle looks like:

```
    val documentationDir = file("documentation")
    val documentationSnippetsDir = file("build/generated-snippets")
    "asciidoctor"(AsciidoctorTask::class) {
        setConfigurations(listOf("asciidoctorExtensions"))
        setOutputDir(file("build/documentation"))
        inputs.dir(documentationSnippetsDir)
        setSourceDir(documentationDir)
        setBaseDir(documentationDir)
        attributes(mapOf("snippets" to documentationSnippetsDir))
        baseDirFollowsSourceFile()
        asciidoctorj {
            fatalWarnings(listOf(missingIncludes()))
        }
    }
```

With SB2.7.9 was working correctly, now I can't find where is the problem.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Support for documenting request parameters has been [removed in Spring REST Docs 3.0 and replaced with support for documenting form and query parameters separately](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/wiki/Spring-REST-Docs-3.0-Release-Notes#request-parameters-support-removed):

> #### Request Parameters Support Removed
>
> Support for documenting request parameters has been removed. Request parameters are a server-side construct of the Servlet API that mix form and query parameters together. To provide accurate, client-focussed documentation, form and query parameters should be documented separately.
>
> As a result of this change, when using Spring Framework’s MockMvc, you may have to update how your tests send parameters to your API. Instead of using `param` to populate the server-side map of request parameters, `queryParam` (for query parameters) or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`  body content (for form parameters) should be used instead.

In addition to updating your tests to adapt to this change, you should also update your `.adoc` file to reference the `query-parameters` and/or `form-parameters` snippet in place of the `request-parameters` snippet.